# Jena querying specific remote SPARQL endpoint raises HttpException: 404

Tags: java, sparql, jena, endpoint

I am using Jena to send SPARQL queries to remote endpoints. This works well for most of the endpoints. However, it doesn't work for the specific one that I need http://ff-news.ontotext.com/sparql as it gives a `HttpException: 404`. However, the code works fine for `DBpedia` and many other endpoints.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import at.jku.dke.hilal.analysis_graphs.DimensionsToAnalysisSituation;
import at.jku.dke.hilal.md_elements.Dimension;
import at.jku.dke.hilal.owl_handler.BasicOWLHandler;
import org.apache.jena.graph.NodeFactory;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Triple;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.Individual;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Node;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementTriplesBlock;

public class SparqlQuery extends Query {    

    public static void main (String [] args){                   

        String queryString = "select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 10";                     
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString) ;

        System.out.println(queryString);

        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://ff-news.ontotext.com/sparql", query);        
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try end point is http://ff-news.ontotext.com/repositories/factforge_2016

While http://ff-news.ontotext.com/sparql is the web UI. We should provide more explicit instructions for this. The Jena adapter of GraphDB has nothing to do with this indeed

Answer (score 1):

404 means the request got the remote server and the remote server rejected it with "Not Found".

"http://ff-news.ontotext.com/sparql" is some sort of HTML/webapp page. It is not clear that it is the SPARQL endpoint.  The "link to query" button shows a URL but that does not work either.